# Send some arguments to a PHP using the iPhone

Tags: php, iphone

I need to send some arguments from the iPhone to a php in the server

PHP:

```
$text = $_GET['text']);
$mail = $_GET['mail']);
$phone = $_GET['phone']);
```

iPhone SDK

```
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]; //very long text
NSString *mail = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"any@any.com"];
NSString *phone = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"456233876"];
```

How can I send this strings to the PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you'd create an HTTP POST request with NSURLConnection to post the fields "text", "mail", and "phone":

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/page.php"]];
NSMutableString *postBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"text=%@", [@"very long text" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendFormat:@"&mail=%@", [@"any@any.com" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendFormat:@"&phone=%@", [@"1231231234" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[req setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

// Now, implement NSURLConnection delegate methods such as connectionDidFinishLoading: and connection:didFailWithError: to do something with the response from the server.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use GET or POST data, as normal. It's very simple. Then use an NSURLConnection to send the data, and change the method to POST. Or you can use GET, and just send a URL like http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?var1=abc&var2=def etc.

See
[Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)